# Are these RDFs the same thing?

Tags: rdf, jena, rdfs

I saved and generated these RDFs using the Jena API, and it came out as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF 
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xml:base="urn:uuid:">

<rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/Animal"/>

<rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/Cat">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://example.org/Animal"/>
</rdfs:Class>

<rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/Dog">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://example.org/Animal"/>
</rdfs:Class>


</rdf:RDF>
```

Used Jena API and result

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/Dog">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/Animal"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </rdfs:Class>
  <rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/Cat">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://example.org/Animal"/>
  </rdfs:Class>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I understand that rdf:resource can be rephrased as rdf:about.
But why was rdfs:Classrdf:about="http://example.org/Animal"/ omitted?

Also, what is expressed as rdf:resource and what is expressed as rdf:about?

Comment: there are no "RDFs" - there is only one RDF being a language of the Semenatic Web. You can call it RDF datsets or RDF graphs or Set of RDF triples

Comment: I also don't get your description. You used Jena twice and got different serializations in RDF/XML? Or how exactly did you create both datasets?

Comment: Isn't there a word RDF Schema (RDFs)?
The first RDF/XML is an example of the book I have read.

Comment: For the second RDF/XML, I read and write the first RDF/XML using the Jena API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, semantically, these two RDF/XML files serialize the same RDF. You can verify this for example by converting them to N-Triples, e.g. with Jena’s `riot` command-line tool:

```
riot --syntax=rdfxml --out=ntriples rdf.xml > rdf.nt
```

Both RDF/XML files will convert to (after sorting):

```
<http://example.org/Animal> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class> .
<http://example.org/Cat> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class> .
<http://example.org/Cat> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <http://example.org/Animal> .
<http://example.org/Dog> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class> .
<http://example.org/Dog> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <http://example.org/Animal> .
```

#### About RDF/XML

> But why was `<rdfs:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/Animal"/>` omitted?

It exists in both files. In the second file, it’s nested in an `<rdfs:subClassOf>` element. RDF/XML allows for many such variations.

> what is expressed as `rdf:resource` and what is expressed as `rdf:about`?

The `rdf:resource` attribute allows for a shorter representation, but can only be used in certain cases. See [Empty Property Elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-rdf-syntax-grammar-20140225/#section-Syntax-empty-property-elements) in the spec:

> When a predicate arc in an RDF graph points to an object node which has no further predicate arcs, which appears in RDF/XML as an empty node element `<rdf:Description rdf:about="..."> </rdf:Description>` (or `<rdf:Description rdf:about="..." />`) this form can be shortened. This is done by using the IRI of the object node as the value of an XML attribute `rdf:resource` on the containing property element and making the property element empty.

NB: Unless you *have* to use RDF/XML, I would recommend using an RDF serialization like Turtle. It’s way easier to read/understand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and sincere response