# Are those 2 RDF/XML snippets semantically equivalent?

Tags: rdf, rdf-xml

I am experimenting with converting RDF to another format (JSON-LD in this case, via [RDFLib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) and back to RDF.
The resulting RDF is a tad different from the original, and although as a human both kinda make sense, I do wonder if they are actually semantically exactly the same.

**Are the 2 following snippets interchangeable in RDF?**

Original:

```xml
<cim:Substation rdf:ID="_1234">
    <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>A substation</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
</cim:Substation>
```

The back and forth converted snippet:

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="_1234">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="cim:Substation"/>
    <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>A substation</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: yes they denote the same semantics

Comment: You can check/verify this by converting the RDF/XML to a serialization that is more human-friendly and closer to the concept of triples, and then compare the output. See: [Are these RDFs the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74460743/19579546)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these two snippets are definitely not equivalent. This can be verified by using a converter (such as [this one](https://www.easyrdf.org/converter)), and choosing a more basic RDF serialization format, such as N-Triples.

Input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xml:base="example:base/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:cim="example:cim#">
    <cim:Substation rdf:ID="_1234">
        <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>A substation</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
    </cim:Substation>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Output:

```
<example:base/#_1234> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <example:cim#Substation> .
<example:base/#_1234> <example:cim#IdentifiedObject.name> "A substation" .
```

Input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xml:base="example:base/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:cim="example:cim#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="_1234">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="cim:Substation"/>
        <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>A substation</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Output:

```
<example:base/_1234> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <cim:Substation> .
<example:base/_1234> <example:cim#IdentifiedObject.name> "A substation" .
```

There are two differences in these two snippets:

- `rdf:ID="name"` is (more or less) an abbreviation of `rdf:about="#name"` (notice the `#`). If you care about the document using stable URIs for its resources, using `rdf:about="name"` will produce different URIs, as you can see from the N-Triples output ‒ one has `example:base/#_1234` and the other has `example:base/_1234`. The only situation where this *might* be equivalent is if the parser/formatter chose a different XML base for the second snippet (e.g. `example:base#` as opposed to `example:base`), *and* interpreted the absolute URI formation of `example:base#`+`_1234` as `example:base#_1234`, which is nevertheless *incorrect*, as `example:base#`+`_1234` is `example:_1234`.
- The usage of `cim:Substation` as an XML element name is not resolved in the same way as the value of `rdf:resource`. In the former case, the XML namespace is used and concatenated with the element's local name (resulting in `example:cim#Substation`), while in the latter case, it is simply treated as a plain URI. This would be equivalent only if the prefix `cim:` is supposed to denote the namespace `cim:` (i.e. having `xmlns:cim="cim:"` in the original snippet) which it might not.